# Problems compiling a generic table component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I am attempting to implement a table using generics in Typescript. The code I am using is based on a table component provided at:

```
https://www.bekk.christmas/post/2020/22/create-a-generic-table-with-react-and-typescript
```

I am uncertainn if the author of this code tested it before publishing it. Most of it appears to work, but there is a single compilation problem that I am hoping to get some insights on.

The test data provided is pretty straightforward:

```
interface Cat {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  gender: string;
  color: string;
  activityLevel?: string; // optional, same as string | undefined
  favoriteFood?: string; // optional, same as string | undefined
}
```

The main (Table) component, with props, is below. It is Table.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import TableHeader from "./TableHeader";
import TableRows from "./TableRows";

export type ColumnDefinitionType<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    key: K;
    header: string;
    width?: number;
}

export type TableProps<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    data: Array<T>;
    columns: Array<ColumnDefinitionType<T, K>>;
}

const style = {
    borderCollapse: 'collapse'
} as const

const Table = <T, K extends keyof T>({ data, columns }: TableProps<T, K>): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <table style={style}>
            <TableHeader columns={columns} />
            <TableRows
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
            />
        </table>
    );
};

export default Table;
```

The component design is pretty straightforward. The Table component has a header and body component.

The header component, TableHeader.tsx, is below:

```
import React from "react";
import {ColumnDefinitionType} from "./Table";

type TableHeaderProps<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    columns: Array<ColumnDefinitionType<T, K>>;
}

const TableHeader = <T, K extends keyof T>({ columns }: TableHeaderProps<T, K>): JSX.Element => {
    const headers = columns.map((column, index) => {
        const style = {
            width: column.width ?? 100, // 100 is our default value if width is not defined
            borderBottom: '2px solid black'
        };

        return (
            <th
                key={`headCell-${index}`}
                style={style}
            >
                {column.header}
            </th>
        );
    });

    return (
        <thead>
        <tr>{headers}</tr>
        </thead>
    );
};

export default TableHeader;
```

The body component, called TableRow.tsx, is below:

```
import React from "react";
import {ColumnDefinitionType} from "./Table";

type TableRowsProps<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    data: Array<T>;
    columns: Array<ColumnDefinitionType<T, K>>;
}

const style = {
    border: '1px solid black'
}

const TableRows = <T, K extends keyof T>({ data, columns }: TableRowsProps<T, K>): JSX.Element => {
    const rows = data.map((row, index) => {
        return (
            <tr key={`row-${index}`}>
                {columns.map((column, index2) => {
                        return (
                            <td key={`cell-${index2}`} style={style}>
                                {row[column.key]}
                            </td>
                        );
                    }
                )}
            </tr>
        );
    });

    return (
        <tbody>
        {rows}
        </tbody>
    );
};

export default TableRows;
```

For completeness, I am including the code for invoking the Table component:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Table from './Table';

interface Cat {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  gender: string;
  color: string;
  activityLevel?: string; // optional, same as string | undefined
  favoriteFood?: string; // optional, same as string | undefined
}

const data: Cat[] = [
  {
    name: "Mittens",
    color: "black",
    age: 2,
    gender: "female",
    activityLevel: "hight",
    favoriteFood: "milk",
  },
  {
    name: "Mons",
    color: "grey",
    age: 2,
    gender: "male",
    favoriteFood: "old socks",
    activityLevel: "medium",
  },
  {
    name: "Luna",
    color: "black",
    age: 2,
    gender: "female",
    activityLevel: "medium",
    favoriteFood: "fish",
  },
  {
    name: "Bella",
    color: "grey",
    age: 1,
    gender: "female",
    activityLevel: "high",
    favoriteFood: "mice",
  },
  {
    name: "Oliver",
    color: "orange",
    age: 1,
    gender: "male",
    activityLevel: "low",
    favoriteFood: "fish",
  },
];

const columns: ColumnDefinitionType<Cat, keyof Cat>[] = [
  {
    key: 'name',
    header: 'Name',
    width: 150
  },
  {
    key: 'age',
    header: 'Age in years',
  },
  {
    key: 'color',
    header: 'Color'
  }
]

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table data={data} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I attempt to compile this code, I am seeing one problem in the TableRow component. I get the following compilation error:

```
ERROR in src/TableRows.tsx:20:33
TS2322: Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
    Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
      Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
        Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.
          Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.
            Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.
              Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.
                Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.
                  Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.
    18 |                         return (
    19 |                             <td key={`cell-${index2}`} style={style}>
  > 20 |                                 {row[column.key]}
       |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    21 |                             </td>
    22 |                         );
    23 |                     }
```

I have looked at documentation for React and Typescript, and I cannot see a reason for that line of code to fail to compile. Perhaps my understanding of string- based indexes is flawed?

Can someone give some idea of why this line of code is failing, and how I can get this TableRows component to work?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your files in jsx files (not typescript) and it all worked with no errors. Maybe "key" is a "saved" word for typescript or something like that...

Good luck!